# Fixing points as non-outliers during outlier detection in Python

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, scikit-learn, outliers

I found this Scikit Learn page explaining how to use different algorithms to detect outliers:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html

Is it possible to set a group of instances as non-outliers so that the algorithms understand that those specific points should not be detected as outliers?

Comment: No one is *removing* anything - outliers are just *detected*.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited the question, but the doubt remains: is it possible to fix a group of points to be considered non-outliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough so called non-outliers for training, one option is to use [Novelty detection with Local Outlier Factor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_lof_novelty_detection.html) . You will train using all your non-outliers, then try to detect outliers with the rest of the data

Comment: Thanks! I think that worked out!

Comment: cool. glad it was useful :)